# Beamer: Strange spacing in references with biblatex apa-style

Tags: beamer, spacing, biblatex, apa-style

I stumbled upon these two spacing errors (marked with red numbers):
[image]

I guess the first space is not really an error, but simply English spacing (`\nonfrenchspacing`). Can it be turned off (without changing the language)? `\frenchspacing` does not seem to have an effect on the references.

But I don't understand where the second spacing error is coming from. Has anyone got a clue?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber,doi,url]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@article {Thomas1975,
  author = {Thomas, Ewart and Weaver, Wanda},
  title = {Cognitive processing and time perception},
  journal = {Attention, Perception, \& Psychophysics},
  issn = {1943-3921},
  pages = {363--367},
  volume = {17},
  doi = {10.3758/BF03199347},
  year = {1975}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}

\frame{\textcite{Thomas1975}}
\frame{\printbibliography}

\end{document}
```

Without beamer (`\documentclass{article}`) everything looks fine:

[image]

Comment: There is no `foobar` key in your `literature.bib`

Comment: The second space is definitely a spurious space. But I'm not sure about the first. That might not be an error. (I can't select only half the space…)

Comment: Does the second space appear without beamer?

Comment: Without beamer everything is fine.

Comment: Could you check your `beamer` version: might be a bug!

Comment: @JosephWright The spurious space after the title goes away if you remove `\newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}` in `\apptocmd{\abx@macro@title}` from `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`. The standard styles don't appear to have this problem, though.

Comment: @JosephWright: I'm using TexLive 2011 on Debian Squeeze. Package: beamer, revision: 26288, cat-version: 3.18, cat-date: 2012-05-10 17:51:02 +0200

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spacing and punctuation issues are associated with patches `beamer` applies to `biblatex` bibliography macros for changing colours within bibliography items. These can be found in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`.

Extra whitespace in the first problem is associated with `\usebeamercolor`. This can be resolved by issuing `biblatex`'s `\unspace`.

To solve the second problem we can set punctuation before changing the colour. This will suppress any spurious punctuation generated by `\newunit` or `\setunit` in the existing drivers and bibliography macros.

Here are some revised patches demonstrating these ideas. A new patch for the `labeltitle` bibliography macro handles the case where author-year styles use `label` or `labeltitle` as a fallback for `labelname`.

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}
    {\apptocmd{\blx@env@bibliography}
       {\let\makelabel\beamer@biblabeltemplate}{}{}
     \apptocmd{\abx@macro@begentry}
       {\let\bbx@tempa\@empty%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}}{}{}
     \pretocmd{\abx@macro@labeltitle}
       {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcsundef{abx@field@label}}
          and test {\ifcsundef{abx@field@labeltitle}} }{}{\let\bbx@tempa\labelnamepunct}}{}{}
     \pretocmd{\abx@macro@title}
       {\ifcsundef{abx@name@labelname}{}{\let\bbx@tempa\labelnamepunct}%
        \bbx@tempa\newblock\unspace\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}}{}{}
     \apptocmd{\abx@macro@title}
       {\ifcsundef{abx@field@title}{}{\newunitpunct}%
        \newblock\unspace\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}{}{}}
    {}}
```

Instead of editing the `beamer` style file, you can modify the existing patches just after `\begin{document}`.

```
...
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\abx@macro@begentry}{\let\bbx@tempa\@empty}{}{}
\pretocmd{\abx@macro@labeltitle}
  {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcsundef{abx@field@label}}
     and test {\ifcsundef{abx@field@labeltitle}} }{}{\let\bbx@tempa\labelnamepunct}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\abx@macro@title}
  {\ifcsundef{abx@name@labelname}{}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct}}
  {\ifcsundef{abx@name@labelname}{}{\let\bbx@tempa\labelnamepunct}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\abx@macro@title}
  {\newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}}
  {\bbx@tempa\newblock\unspace\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\abx@macro@title}
  {\ifcsundef{abx@field@title}{}{\blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct}}
  {\ifcsundef{abx@field@title}{}{\newunitpunct}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\abx@macro@title}
  {\newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}
  {\newblock\unspace\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}{}{}
\makeatother
\nocite{Thomas1975,ctan,cms,companion,britannica,kant:ku}
\frame[allowframebreaks]{\printbibliography}
\end{document}
```

Here's your entry printed with some [different bibliography margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46266/4483).

[image]

The patches appear to give the desired effect for standard `biblatex` styles, but thorough testing is needed. The solution doesn't resolve issues for a few (hopefully edge) cases in `biblatex-apa`. These include entries that don't have any data to form a label (i.e. `labelname`, `label`, `labeltitle` and `labelyear` all missing) and `biblatex-apa`'s overriding of `useeditor` and friends per-entry option settings (e.g. `britannica` in the above document).

Unresolved issues are probably worse for some other contributed styles. Surely `beamer` can't account for all of them. Perhaps the best approach is to have style authors tailor the patches as needed.

Comment: I'll take a look at this. Note that `\usebeamercolor` does not add any space _per se_: it's the whatsit that is the issue.

Comment: @Audrey: I tried to apply your patch, but I couldn't make it work. I looked at the related question you linked and removed the first two lines with their corresponding curly brackets. Then I put the code right behind `\begin{document}` between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. The code caused no error, but made no change either. Could you perhaps give an example of how to apply your patch on my example given above? Thank you!

Comment: @JosephWright OK. I corrected the sentence, but feel free to edit it further to clarify.

Comment: @deboerk Inside the document, you have to work with the edits made from the existing patches. I added an example.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is one that I suspected could occur: adding `beamer` colours to bibliographies is something of a hack, and is more risky with `biblatex` than with traditional BibTeX styles.

When adding to `biblatex` styles, we have to target the drivers 'during' the formatting: with traditional BibTeX, it's essentially done 'after' the formatting. That's an issue because the formatting produced by `biblatex` depends on the output, but the colour-control inserts affect that. For example, the standard `biblatex` set up is

```
\newbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}
```

whereas for the `apa` style it's

```
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{title}\AND\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{origtitle}
      {\printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[apacase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[apacase]{subtitle}}}%
      {\printfield{origtitle}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printtext[brackets]{%
        \printfield[apacase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[apacase]{subtitle}}}
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{titleaddon}%
     \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{book}%
       {\setunit{\addspace}\usebibmacro{bookaddinfo}}%
       {}%
     \ifthenelse{%
       \ifnameundef{author}\AND%
       \(\ifnameundef{editor}\AND\NOT\boolean{bbx:editorinauthpos}\)\AND%
       \ifnameundef{namea}\AND%
       \ifnameundef{nameb}}
        {\newunit\newblock
         \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}
        {}}}
```

The important line here is `\setunit{\addspace}`: it will insert a space 'after' the current material. Unfortunately, the colour code is seen as 'output' by `biblatex` (there is a whatsit in the output stream, which prevents `biblatex` 'seeing' what is going on).

Now, the question is what to do about this. I'm not sure there is a general fix, as the appropriate place to insert the colour code depends on the `biblatex` driver in use. So perhaps the best thing that can be done is to offer an option not to add in any colours.

Comment: I would appreciate an option to turn off colors for the references. At the moment I always have to adjust the beamer theme and color everything black.