# Beamer: allowframebreaks collides with columns?

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, columns

I'm doing a scientific presentation with the beamer package and have two columns  (the left one with text, the right one with several images) that are too long for one frame.
 I want to use `[allowframebreaks]` . The code does compile, but in the resulting pdf, the text and images just disappear under the bottom of the frame and no new frame is made. Here's an example code:

```
\documentclass[18p]{beamer}

\newcommand{\graph}[2]{
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=#2]{#1} % #1= Name, #2=Size
\end{center} 
\end{figure} }

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Analysis}
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Once upon a time
      \item in the magical land
      \item of Equestria,
      \item there were two regal sisters
      \item who ruled together
      \item and created harmony for all the land.
      \item To do this,
      \item the elder used her
      \item unicorn powers
      \item to raise the sun at dawn.
      \item The younger
      \item brought out the moon
      \item to begin the night.
     \end{itemize}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
    \graph{rainbowdash.jpeg}{0.5}
    \graph{20percentcooler.jpeg}{0.2}
    \graph{molestia_hot_plot}{0.3}
    \graph{cupcakes.jpeg}{0.6}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there any possibility to use [allowframebreaks] and columns at the same time?

Thanks!
dervonnebenaan

Comment: No. `column` is essentially `minipage` and does not allow breaks.  `\allowframebreaks` is intended for things such as bibliographies that are internally generated but may spill over several frames.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Make that an answer, plaese.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`column` is essentially `minipage` and does not allow breaks accross frames.  In a presentation, you should think of your audience and make the critical decisions about exactly how much material should be on each frame, what material is visible simultaneously.

The option `[allowframebreaks]` is really intended for things such as bibliographies that are internally generated but may spill over several frames, and usual don't form a part of the main presentation.  Indeed the beamer documentation says

> - Do not use the option allowframebreaks except for long bibliographies.
> - Do not use long bibliographies.

and later about `[allowframebreaks]`

> The use of this option is *evil*. In a (good) presentation you prepare each slide carefully and think twice before putting something on a certain slide rather than on some different slide.

As @Daniel points out `[allowframebreaks]` also switches off some `beamer` presentation features such as overlays.

Comment: One of my favorite comments on beamer which I found in a different place is: "As shown multiple times in the manual the author likes to indicate his personal opinion with quite strong wording. This quote is one such occasion. It is rather useless to argue about that and especially use them in technical discussions such as this one. There are various ways to make use of the combination of the two respective features with very good reasons that neither the author of any latex package nor we the stackexchange community are entitled to judge."